# Browsers no longer go to their home page

Tags: firefox, windows-7

I've gotten used to my browser opening to its home page, but with Windows 7, they now open the last page they were on before I closed the browser.

How do I change the browser's behavior to open the home page when the browser is opened?

Comment: More of a superuser question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox: Tools->Options->tab General->first dropdown->select "show home page"

IE8: Tools->Internet Options->tab General->in the "Tabs" part, button Settings->checkbox "Only open the first home page when starting Internet Explorer"; in the same form, "when opening new tab, show..."->"home page"

Opera: (Menu)->Settings->Preferences->tab General->Startup->Start with home page

Midori: Edit->Preferences->General->When Midori starts->show home page

Comment: (I'm quoting the names from memory, as I don't have an English version of IE here, so the labels might not be completely accurate)

Comment: Your description was good enough for me to be able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

**Firefox** - Tools > Options > General > When Firefox Starts > Deselect the "Show my windows and tabs from last time".

**IE** - See @Piskvor's answer.

**Chrome** - Options > On startup > make sure either the "Open the homepage" or "Open the following pages:" option is selected.